# ColdFusion event gateways are taking long time to generate huge number of PDF files

Tags: coldfusion, event-gateway

In our ColdFusion application an event gateway is used to generate PDF files (more than 250 000) for Arabic texts and English text. During this process we noticed that event gateways are getting stuck frequently (sometimes after half an hour or an hour or after 20 minutes etc.). And we need to restart the gateways frequently to start the processing again. Also it is taking an average of 40 hrs to finish the processing of all the PDF files.

Can someone suggest a better solution for this in ColdFusion.

Comment: I think the cause of the problem is sheer volume of work, not the programming language.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a CLI and not a web app. Have you considered doing this with CommandBox? You could write a task runner that loops through all the files and does the conversion.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: ColdFusion9 we are using. As part of migration we tested this ColdFusion 2018 as well but still not much improvement on time taken

Comment: @Dan Bracuk, may I know why you are saying  “sheer volume of work”??

Comment: @Redtopia, may I how does it make a difference if we use CommandBox.

Comment: @user3742125 CommandBox is a CLI, so it doesn’t have all the baggage of a web application. You can write “Task Runners” that can be run from the command line that run for as long as they take. CommandBox brings CLI development to the world of ColdFusion.

Comment: How often are you doing this much generation? Are you also running other parts of your site through ColdFusion? There are some pretty significant differences between CF9 and 2018. If PDF generation is taking the same time, then you'll want to take a look at how those PDFs are being generated. CF2018 should be significantly faster for pretty much anything, especially if the code is updated to use more modern conventions. There may be other pieces in your generation code that are slowing things down. One other thing I'll mention about CF2018 is that security is _SIGNIFICANTLY_ improved.

Comment: And one other thought, if you're using CF9, you're probably using a cfloop to iterate through the 250K records to make PDFs. That may not be the most efficient way to process these things.